# Is there a category name for pictures where an object fills a relatively small part of the frame against a bold, single-color background?

Tags: color, terminology

I am a web developer whose knowledge about photography is very limited. I am trying to find keywords to search for more pictures like the following. [image] where there is a picture of an object with pure solo color in the background.

Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated

Comment: What are some of the descriptive words that come to your mind ? What makes you think they would share  a common descriptor or key word ? what is it in these images that speaks to you ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan OP is a web developer. He's looking for stock images with space over which to superimpose text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really a category, as such, but the large areas of your example images that are mostly uniform are referred to as [*negative space*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/21351/15871). That is, they are spaces that do not have distinguishing details in them in the way the smaller main subject of the image does.

If you search stock image sites for images with negative space, you'll likely get the kind of results you are looking for.